# Matlab nearest neighbor / track points

Tags: performance, matlab, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

I have a set of `n` complex numbers that move through the complex plane from time step `1` to `nsampl` . I want to plot those numbers and their trace over time (y-axis shows imaginary part, x-axis the real part). The numbers are stored in a `n x nsampl` vector. However in each time step the order of the `n` points is random. Thus in each time step I pick a point in the last time step, find its nearest neighbor in the current time step and put it at the same position as the current point. Then I repeat that for all other `n-1` points and go on to the next time step. This way every point in the previous step is associated with exactly one point in the new step (1:1 relation). My current implementation and an example are given below. However my implementation is terribly slow (takes about 10s for 10 x 4000 complex numbers). As I want to increase both, the set size `n` and the time frames `nsampl` this is really important to me. Is there a smarter way to implement this to gain some performance?

Example with n=3 and nsampl=2:

```
%manually create a test vector X
X=zeros(3,2); % zeros(n,nsampl)
X(:,1)=[1+1i; 2+2i; 3+3i];
X(:,2)=[2.1+2i; 5+5i; 1.1+1.1i]; % <-- this is my vector with complex numbers

%vector sort algorithm
for k=2:nsampl
    Xlast=[real(X(:,k-1)) imag(X(:,k-1))];          % create vector with x/y-coords from last time step
    Xcur=[real(X(:,k)) imag(X(:,k))];               % create vector with x/y-coords from current time step
    for i=1:size(X,1) % loop over all n points
        idx = knnsearch(Xcur(i:end,:),Xlast(i,:));  %find nearest neighbor to Xlast(i,:), but only use the points not already associated, thus Xcur(i:end,:) points
        idx = idx + i - 1;
        Xcur([i idx],:) = Xcur([idx i],:);          %sort nearest neighbor to the same position in the vector as it was in the last time step
    end
    X(:,k) = Xcur(:,1)+1i*Xcur(:,2);                %revert x/y coordinates to a complex number
end
```

Result:

```
X(:,2)=[1.1+1.1i; 2.1+2i; 5+5i];
```

Can anyone help me to speed up this code?

Comment: Is it necessary to replicate exactly the behaviour of your algorithm? Especially the fact that two points in step k (lets say 1st and 2nd) have the 7th point of step k+1 as it's neighbour, moving it twice.

Comment: Or to further precise my previous comment, your descriptions sounds like "matching of a weighted bipartite graph" (minimizing the weight) and your code does a greedy version of it, which approximates an optimal solution.

Comment: I hope I understand your comment right, since I don't know anything about bipartite graphs. I guess I doesn't have to replicate the exact same behavior, as long as there is still a 1:1 relation (i.e. `X(:,2)=[1.1+1.1i; 2.1+2i; 2.1+2i]` would be wrong, since it found the same nearest neighbor twice for two different ancestors.

Comment: Okay, let's simplify the discussion. Take the example `X(:,1)=[1.6,2.6,3.6]` `X(:,2)=[1,2,3]`. As I understood your text it is already matched right, but your algorithm starts to swap.

Comment: Yes, my algorithm would falsely swap that. That's not intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are tying to solve is combinatorial optimizartion which is solved by [the hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) (aka `munkres`). Luckily there is a implementation for matlab [available for download.](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20652-hungarian-algorithm-for-linear-assignment-problems--v2-3-) Download the file and put it either on your search path or next to your function. The code to use it is:

```
for k=2:size(X,2)
   %build up a cost matrix, here cost is the distance between two points.
   pairwise_distances=abs(bsxfun(@minus,X(:,k-1),X(:,k).'));
   %let the algorithm find the optimal pairing
   permutation=munkres(pairwise_distances);
   %apply it
   X(:,k)=X(permutation,k);
end
```